# Saving an image from the internet to iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to download an image from the internet. I'm not sure why this code is not working when I want to get the photos with these specs (209x209 pixels,not more than 65KB).

Writing to iPhone directory:

```
NSData *imgAsData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]]; 
//UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData thumnail_url]];    
NSFileHandle* myFileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:self.product.img_url];
[myFileHandle writeData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
[myFileHandle closeFile];
```

I even tried writeToFile, but it still doesn't work.

```
[imgAsData writeToURL: [NSURL URLWithString:self.product.img_url] atomically:YES];
```

Reading from iPhone directory:

```
NSFileHandle* myFileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:self.product.img_url];
//NSFileHandle* myFileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:self.product.thumbnail_url];
UIImage* loadedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[myFileHandle readDataToEndOfFile]];
```

I was using this code in the same app to download thumbnails and they are working (notice the commented out lines using the "thumbnail_url"). I tried to substitute the thumbnail url in the place of this "larger" image and it worked. I was able to save the thumbnail offline, but I need to get the larger version (since, of course, the thumbnails are too pixelated).

I'm sure that the paths are ok since I got the thumnails working.

I'm lost. Is this not working because the file size is "larger"? Help please, Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the paths to larger images are OK? Can you NSLog a path and copy-paste it in a browser to see if the image appears?

Comment: @camden_kid for the thumbnail image it appears in the browser when I paste the url. But not for the larger image...

Comment: That tells me that the url for the larger image may not be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath can not create a file.  You need to create the file first.

Comment: But how come it works for the thumbnail images? I meant, it can write files for the thumbnail images... Do you mean that I have to make the file path first? I made the path in another part of my code already... I'm just using it here.

Comment: The file needs to exist at the path.  If you already know the path you can just write the image out like this `[imgAsData writeToDisk];`.

Comment: Also, debug your code an make sure that you're downloading an image.  Look at size for UIImage and validate it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

To save images to iPhone simply use

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(<#UIImage *image#>, <#id completionTarget#>, <#SEL completionSelector#>, <#void *contextInfo#>)
```

If you want to save images only 209*209 then add a check before that on the dimension of an image. I don't know(yet) how to read the images from iPhone, but you can use [`UIImagePickerController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) to choose the images.

Hope it helps

Comment: I want to try this one out too. Thanks @Novarg